# useMutation refetchQueries not updating with no-cache

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I set cookie-usage-option to 'no-cache' with defaultOptions like below.

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "[API_URL]",
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  defaultOptions: {
    watchQuery: {
      fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
      errorPolicy: 'ignore',
    },
    query: {
      fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
      errorPolicy: 'all',
    },
    mutate: {
      fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
      errorPolicy: 'all',
    },
  },
});
```

But It occurs a problem after this.

```
...

const {
    data: todos,
  } = useQuery(GET_ALL_TODOS);
const [createTodo] = useMutation(CREATE_TODO);

const handleCreateTodo = useCallback(() => {
  createTodo({
    variables: {
      title: 'test title',
    },
  });
}, []);

...
```

With this code.
Before applying the no-cache, 
When I call a function `handleCreateTodo`(a button click event), the component is re-rendered and `todos` is also updated.

After applying the no-cache, 
When I call the event `handleCreateTodo`, the component isn't re-rendered.

In my thoughts, a data of the useQuery was used a cached-data. and queries of `refetchQueries` made the cached-data updated.
the useQuery detected changing the cached-data so It made the component re-rendered.

I guess but I'm not sure. 
How does `refetchQueries` work and Why doesn't it make a component updated after no-cache option?

Comment: Do you update the state after the API call?

Comment: @Ar26 No, I didn't. useQuery was updated automatically after calling the mutation.